# How to delete small independent masks from images?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, opencv

I have binarized image. Yellow = 1 mask, purple = 0 background:

[image]

I can filter if the whole masks is small by some threshold this way:

```
def filter_image(img):
    if img.sum() < 10:
        return np.zeros(img.shape)
    else:
        return img
```

However how get rid of this small yellow points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can be easily done with a Morphological Transformation

You can check the docs [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html)

Something like this should work:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('some_image.png',0)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

You can play with the values inside the kernel to close the holes with a determinate size.

I hope it helped

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I might suggest to quote the minimal relevant part of the documentation/tutorial in addition to the link, just in case the URL ever moves. Hope to see you around more!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use sequential [morphological dilations and erosions](https://scialert.net/fulltext/?doi=ajsr.2015.291.303) in order to remove this noise.

These operation are also known as [open](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#opening) and [close](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#closing).